# WPF Programatically send KeyDown event to ListBox so that selection is changed

Tags: wpf, listbox

I want to be able to send programmatically a key event so that the selection in a ListBox can change (up or down).

Here is a simplified example:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListBox Name="TestPanel"  Width="200" Height="150" >
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem IsSelected="True">First</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Fourth</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>                
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the Button_Click event, I would like to be able to send a **Down** KeyDown event that will get the selection down by one in the list box.
I have tried to just send a KeyDown event to the ListBox but it has no effect:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var key = Key.Down;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Sending key event: {key}");
    TestPanel.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        PresentationSource.FromVisual(TestPanel),
        0, key
        )
    { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent });
}
```

Edit:

More context:
As mentioned in the comments, in my code I am actually using a stack panel as the container for the ItemsPanel. So the "next item" when pressing "down" is not the item with the next index. And each time the window is resized, the number of item in each row could change.

Navigating with the actual keyboard arrows is working fine. So the framework is able to handle that quite nicely. However, I need an additional navigation device to work (kind of joystick). So when moving the joystick down (and then left, right and up), I was hoping to piggy back on what the framework has already working and send a "Down" keydown event so that it would just navigate nicely.

The alternative I can think of is making all the calculations based on the physical locations items to calculate which item is below the currently selected one. I was hoping I would be able to avoid that as the framework already has a working mechanism. The example provided above is as simple an example as possible to try to just get it to work. If it work (being able to have the event handled) in a simple list, it should hopefully work also for what I really need.

Comment: Why would you not simply set the SelectedItem property?

Comment: The actual use case is more complex. I am using a wrap panel as the container for the ItemsPanel. So the "next item" when I key down could vary depending on the width of the window and the number of items displayed per line.

Actually using the keyboard works well. But I have a need for another way to navigate, where sending arrow keys would have made it easy.

Comment: Not sure i follow your description. Maybe. MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

Comment: Than get the index of the selected item (selectedIndex property), iterate it and than select the next item by seting the selecetedIndex property of the listbox to the iterated value.  But make sure to capture the case that the selected item is the last item.

Comment: I have added more context in the main text. I understand the use of SelectedIndex, but my case is a bit more complex, so it is not a good solution.